# how to set Color

Tags: java

can some one tell me or give me a link where i can learn how to use get and set color in java or android? I mean, ARGB, RGB, FF and things like that. I know that a=alpha g green b blue r red but i dont know how to set colors.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Do you need help creating a Color object? Is there a specific object you are havving issues controlling the colour of?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information in your question. How to get/set color for what? I don't think anyone can answer a question that is so vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [color picker](http://www.colorpicker.com/) to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the java docs for the Color class, the various constructors details the scales used for each of the constructor parameters.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

It also details the the static values availble for common colours, such as Color.BLACK

You would use one of these constructors to create a Color object then pass that in to the object you wish to control the colour of.